# Overflow in SystemVerilog constraints

Tags: system-verilog

Integer types in SystemVerilog, as in most languages, wrap around on overflow.  I was wondering if this is also true in constraints.  For example:

```
class Test;
  rand bit [3:0] a;
  rand bit [3:0] b;

  constraint c { a + b <= 4'h6; }
endclass;
```

When randomizing an object of this class, is it possible to get a solution where `a == 7` and `b == 12`, which would satisfy the constraint since 7 + 12 = 19 which wraps around to 3, and 3 is less than 6?

If so, would it help to formulate the constraint as

```
constraint c { a + b <= 6; }
```

where 6 is a 32-bit signed int and the sum is forced to be calculated with 32-bit precision?  (This of course is not a solution if the random variables are of type `int`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. Expression evaluation is identical whether you are inside a constraint or not. In addition to overflow, you also need to be concerned about truncation and sign conversion. Integral expressions are weakly typed in SystemVerilog.